# Refresh the iframe youtube API

Tags: javascript, html, api, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the iframe API to generate a youtube video embedded on my website.

```js
loadAPIPls('WQBUy6t3f0U');

function loadAPIPls(idYTB) {
  loadYouTubeAPI();
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    createYouTubePlayer(idYTB);
  }
}

function loadYouTubeAPI() {
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}

function createYouTubePlayer(id) {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '360',
    width: '640',
    videoId: id,
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
```

The video is displayed without any problem. The issue arises when I recall the function with another ID without refreshing the page.

button on click `loadAPIPls('DOWDNBu9DkU')` for example.

And the video is not updating, it's the same. I would like the player to update with the new video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found by myself

```
function loadAPIPls(IdYtb) {
  if (typeof YT === 'undefined' || typeof YT.Player === 'undefined') {
      loadYouTubeAPI();
      window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
      createYouTubePlayer(IdYtb);
      }
  } else {
    createYouTubePlayer(IdYtb);
  }
}

function createYouTubePlayer(id) {

  var iframePlayer = document.querySelector("iframe#player");
  if (iframePlayer == null)  {
    // create the YT.Player object if it doesn't exist
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: id,
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      }
    });
  } else {
    load1(id);
  }
}
function load1(id) {
  player.loadVideoById(id);
}
```